# Diesel Engine Sounds like bucket of bolts when starting

Tags: truck

98 kota 3.9Okay here's a question I wrecked my truck and I was in the middle of a build putting three alternators on After I wrecked truck I tried to crank it and it cranked just fine twice to move it for the tow truck guy.. had it towed home, now I'm done with the build and when I go to crank the truck it sounds like there's a bucket of bolts being slung around in the engine.

There were no problems what does starter or anything a friend told me to replace the starter that was the problem so I did. still having the problem though from the accident I replaced everything up to the fan... Grill condenser radiator fan shroud. Damage didn't go past the shroud and did not damage the band blade what the hell could be making this noise it sounds terrible when I try to crank it and it will not crank and the belt is wrapped correctly nothing is binding or too tight

I need some suggestions or ideas ASAP

Video - https://youtu.be/iWYIs5kbbWE

Comment: Is the engine turning when you “crank” it?

Comment: no, can you please watch the video to get idea

Comment: Yes,  I did. That’s why I asked if it was turning.

Comment: I manually tried to turn the engine from underneath and turned it just a little and then tried to crank it again and it I had the noise as if it was going to crank but then it went right back to the clunking sound it likes spun over like once I think

Answer (score 1):

Following your latest update, you could possibly have damaged teeth on your flywheel/ring gear.  After manually turning the engine, the starter will have meshed with good teeth and will have been able to turn the engine over.  When the damaged teeth came around again the teeth will start to grind.

You could take the starter off and examine the teeth on the starter, then look through the starter mounting hole to examine all the teeth on the ring gear.

Also check that the starter was mounted correctly.

Comment: Take off the starter and turn the crank manually.  See if it still grinds.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it could possibly be the starter solenoid rattling on and off.  Check the engine earth strap and the large connections to the battery.

Comment: I manually tried to turn the engine from underneath and turned it just a little and then tried to crank it again and it I had the noise as if it was going to crank but then it went right back to the clunking sound it likes spun over like once I think